# Azure AD B2C integration with SharePoint 2019 on premise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, azure-ad, azure-active-directory

I want to integrate Azure AD B2C with SharePoint 2019 on-premise for managing users and groups. Is it possible?

I read [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga) that "Azure AD B2C is not meant for the SharePoint external partner-sharing scenario; see Azure AD B2B instead". What about SharePoint 2019 on-premise?

Answer (score 0):

Here're some references for you about how to integrate Azure AD B2C with SharePoint 2019 on-premise.

[Tutorial: Azure Active Directory single sign-on integration with SharePoint on-premises](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial)

[SharePoint On-Premises Integration With Azure AD and Guest Accounts](https://sharepointwhoknew.wordpress.com/2019/04/26/sharepoint-on-premises-integration-with-azure-ad-and-guest-accounts/)

Comment: Does it apply to Azure AD B2C as well?

Comment: Yes, it applys to Azure AD B2C as well.

Comment: Hi, we are currently working with AzureAD B2C. From our analysis, as opposed to the statement above, it seems these articles apply to AzureAD only. It is not possible to connect SharePoint directly with B2C, because it does not support WS-Federation. If anyone as another experience, please share updated articles;-)